# get current timer in timer_tick

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have several form timers and they all call the same tick event. How do I get which timer fired inside of the tick event?

```
  void Main_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // need to grab which timer fired this event
  }
```

More specifically, I need to get the timer.tag property.

Comment: var tag = ((Timer)sender).Tag;

Comment: Why do you not use `Elapsed` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sender` is (supposed to be) a reference to the object firing the event. So in your case, you should be able to do something like:

```
((Timer)sender).Tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the timer via the object sender parameter and then cast it as a timer.